# Understanding iPhone crash log

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, crash, uikit

My iPhone game crashed whilst on the device and I am attempting to understand what happened.

Every time a user exits the game screen it will send a message to the `HomePageController` (my top level controller) telling it to save the user data. This works fine all the time except for in this particular instance.  The exception thrown seems to state that `HomePageController` did not recognize the `saveUserData` selector but I can't see how that can happen as that function is definitely in that controller and it works the rest of the time.

Can anyone offer any advice?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0 CoreFoundation      0x3756a88f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1 libobjc.A.dylib     0x35a70259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2 CoreFoundation      0x3756da9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175
3 CoreFoundation      0x3756c915 ___forwarding___ + 301
4 CoreFoundation      0x374c7650 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
5 P------k            0x0000ebe1 -[HomePageController saveUserData] (HomePageController.m:125)
6 P------k            0x00008a0b -[RootViewController viewDidAppear:] (RootViewController.m:102)
```

Line 125 in HomePageController.m:

```
- (void)saveUserData{
    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    //10x10
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
        for (int i = 0; i < _puzzles10x10.count; i++){
            LevelData *currentPuzzle = [_puzzles10x10 objectAtIndex:i];
            /*(line 125)*/ [dict setObject:[currentPuzzle getPuzzleUserData] forKey:currentPuzzle.title];
        }

        [dict writeToFile:[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userdata.dat"] atomically:YES];
    }
    // more here
}
```

Comment: Can you post what is line 125 in your HomePageController.m file ? I think you will find your answer there

Comment: @giorashc Ah yes, that seems obvious now.. Ill update the question, still not entire sure why its crashing on that line

Comment: RootViewController's line 102 would be interesting as well =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `currentPuzzle` doesn't recognize the selector `getPuzzleUserData` then the problem is one of these two:

1. `LevelData` does not define a method `getPuzzleUserData`.
2. `currentPuzzle` is not an instance of `LevelData`

So check if the method is actually defined in the class `LevelData` and not in `HomePageController` and that when you add items to `_puzzles10x10` they are actually instances of `LevelData`.

To debug further, split your code into as many lines as possible (one instruction per line), add a lot of `NSLog` calls and see what happens:

```
NSLog(@"_puzzles10x10: %@", _puzzles10x10);
for (int i = 0; i < _puzzles10x10.count; i++){
    LevelData *currentPuzzle = [_puzzles10x10 objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"currentPuzzle#%d: %@", i, currentPuzzle);
    UserData *userData = [currentPuzzle getPuzzleUserData]; // change UserData to the correct t class
    NSLog(@"userData#%d: %@", i, userData);
    NSString *key = currentPuzzle.title;
    NSLog(@"key#%d: %@", i, key);
    [dict setObject:userData forKey:key];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, LevelData definitely responds to `getPuzzleUserData`.  The user saving code hasnt changed for months and I have only seen this happen once

Comment: It all gets output ok... This is the first time I have ever seen this crash happen. I can show you a selection of the output but it is exactly as I'd expect.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the crash, then it is hard to debug it :) so keep the logs until you get the crash again.

Answer (score 0):

From log it is clear that, you are invoking a method in the object which was not really exist.

```
(2 CoreFoundation      0x3756da9b -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 175)
```

I think the data type of '_puzzles10x10' is changed to some other type by making mistakes in code.

Comment: I think that would be a possible cause of the crash if the code didn't step forward to the line 125. No?

Comment: I think the possible crash is inthe line for (int i = 0; i < _puzzles10x10.count; i++) itself.